# I'm using same py file in VS Code to learn different examples. Why does it still run the first block of code after I delete and write different code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I started with this example:

```
cars = ['audi', 'bmw', 'subaru', 'toyota']

for car in cars:
    if car == 'bmw':
       print(car.upper())
    else:
       print(car.title())
```

I deleted this and moved on to a new example, within same py file:

```
requested_topping = 'mushrooms'

if requested_topping != 'anchovies':
    print("Hold the anchovies!")
```

After I click run on this second code, VS Code still prints the output for the cars example. What could be the matter?

Comment: Did you save the file after making changes?

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebooks? You might need to restart the kernel.

Comment: One really must use jupyter notebooks for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The white dot indicates the file has not been saved.

You can add this in the settings.json file:

```
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
```

to enable the autosave function in the VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is unlikely to be due to the code you've written.  It is likely related to how you're saving your .py file, and how it is being ran.

Are you running the file using the 'play' button / Ctrl+F5 in VSCode, or are you double clicking on the .py file from File Explorer / Finder?

If it's the latter, then perhaps you're not saving the file in VSCode first, try saving the file with Ctrl+S first.

Screenshots would likely go a long way to helping you answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Command n (New file..), convert language mode to python from plain text and paste the new block and run ?